# Pass variable from initializer to handlebars .hbs (Discourse Plugin, maybe Ember in general)

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, discourse

In a `.hbs` file I am creating a navigation menu with various items. One of the items will only display if a user is a pro (boolean).

`var pro` is a variable set in my initializer and I need to pass it my `.hbs` file for the purposes of a conditionally showing one of the menu items.

In Ember, how is this accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

In a such case, we use service to store variables during the application lifecycle. Initializer puts the variables and menu items to service. Menu components retrieve variables from service.

You may also define a helper to retrieve variable from service.

Comment: Ah so put the function in service and define the helper in the initializer which will be available in template?

Comment: Both yes and no. Menu component retrieve menu items from service. menu component's template iterates over these menu items. That's all, we don't need a helper.

Answer (score 0):

I had quite the same problem : I had to use a language variable that is set in my html and I needed to use this language variable in my template. I used a helper to do so : in the helper you can use the variable pro that is set in your initializer (provided you declared it).

example :

```
function myInit(pro) {
   var template = ...;
   var data = ...;
   Handlebars.registerHelper('ifProUser', function(item) {
      if (pro) {
         return "pro menu here";
      } else {
         return "";
      }
   }
   var html = template(data);
   ...
}
```

Then in the template just use :

```
{{ifProInit}}{{/ifProInit}}
```

Comment: So in the hbs template would I then do `{{#if ifProUser}}` ?

Comment: You will use the helper {{ifProUser}}{{/ifProUser}}